# Adding a foreign key, getting errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a foreign key but I am getting below error

> Incorrect syntax near 'EmployeeID'

I am trying to create a foreign key relationship between Employee table and HolidayRequestForm table.

I have a column in both tables called EmployeeID.
EmployeeID is the primary key in the employee table.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EHRF
FOREIGN KEY [EmployeeID] REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee](EmployeeID);
```

Comment: The Column name needs to be wrapped in parenthesis: `... FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeID]) ...`. When getting syntax errors one of the first things you want to check is the documentation; learning to use and read it is a very important skill, and SQL Server's is significantly better than it used to be: [Create a foreign key in an existing table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017#create-a-foreign-key-in-an-existing-table)

Answer (score 5):

You should write:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EHRF
FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee](EmployeeID);
```

Answer (score 4):

Foreign key columns must go into parenthesis

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EHRF
FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee](EmployeeID);
```